# memory overwrite when reading strings in c

Tags: c, string, memory, input, overwrite

The code I am working on needs a vector of doubles as an input and I was trying to make it variable sized, by using [this small library](https://gist.github.com/EmilHernvall/953968) I found on git. A first iteration using strings instead of doubles is:

```c
printf("Write vector components (type 'stop' to stop): \n");
int stop = 0;
while (!stop)
{
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
    if (strcmp("stop\n",c)!=0)
    {
        vector_add(&v, c);
    } else {
        stop = 1;
    }
}
```

However, when I print the result (for example with 3 inputs and "stop") I get

`the vector is:
stop
stop
stop`

I have tried to write the first component everytime I input a new one, and the result is that the last one overwrites the first (and by extension, given the final result, every component).

However, this doesn't happen if I use `vector_add` manually. For example I have tried combining the example from git and my own code and the complete output is:

`emil
hannes
lydia
olle
erik
stop
stop
stop
stop`

So it only overwrites when reading. I can't even begin to comprehend what is happening. Haven't written any C in 2 years and I'm starting all over again.

Full code (not including vector library):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "vector.c"

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char        c[20];
    vector      v; vector_init(&v);


    printf("Write vector components (type 'stop' to stop):\n");
    int stop = 0;
    while (!stop)
    {
        fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
        if (strcmp("stop\n",c)!=0)
        {
            vector_add(&v, c);
            // printf("%s\n", (char*)vector_get(&v, 0));
        } else {
            stop = 1;
        }
    }


    printf("The vector is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_count(&v); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", (char*)vector_get(&v, i));
    }

} /* main */
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code line by line with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector_add` doesn't copy the data, so your string is still stored in the variable `c`. When you read a new string, it overwrites the old one.

If your string library contains `strdup`, you can try this:

```
vector_add(&v, strdup(c));
```